# What is the javascript/window event called when app is launched/opened in firefox OS phones from background?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os

I have a requirement that I want to trigger a javascript function whenever my app in firefox os phone is launched. Below event is called when app is launched initially:

```
window.addEventListner("load",function(){});
```

With this I am able to achieve my requirement on initial launch of the app. Now when I click home icon on phone/simulator my app closes. So whenever I tap on my app it launches and displays same page where I left. At this point I want to make one javascript call or reload the page. Is there any event that I can use during this second launch of the app.

Comment: try "pageshow" event

Answer (score 0):

Use this event:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function(e){
    var currentVisibility = document.visibilityState
    // visible, hidden, prerender, unloaded
    ...
}, false);
```

Check the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) and the [visibilitychange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange)